# CodeIgniter REST server: Store user accounts

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, rest

I am pretty new to CI and trying to build an basic API with user authentication. I found out about [CodeIgniter REST server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver), which seems quite easy to use and covers about everything I need (thank you Philip Sturgeon!).

Unfortunately, the library lacks documentation and I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to store login infomration, other than:

```
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = array('admin' => '1234');
```

I would like to have this information stored in a database instead. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

According to code, this information is being used in two functions in REST_Controller.php:

```
1. _check_logn()
2. _prepare_digest_auth()
```

and it is used as: `$valid_logins = & $this->config->item('rest_valid_logins');`

So if you are storing this info in database, you can load appropriate model here, and retrieve an array and use it instead. For example:

```
$this->load->model('user_info');
$valid_logins = $this->user_info->getValidLogins();
```

Remember your `getValidLogins()` must return an array similar to the one you your have defined in config file i.e. usernames as keys and passwords as values.

P.S.: I haven't tested it. Just followed the code.

Comment: Thanks Vikk!I had a quick look at your suggestion and the code - and if I understand correct - I need to fetch username/password for ALL users very time someone tries to login. Is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily. The only thing being done here is checking that a supplied username exists in our list and passwords match. You can easily modify the code so that you only retrieve the details for supplied username.

Comment: IMO this solution involves password being stored in plain text which is highly insecure. Password should always be hashed (bcrypt) before being stored in database.